# Using multiple instances of getline in C++

Tags: c++, function, overloading, getline

I've been working on a class assignment for C++ and we're required to acquire input from a text file and assign those values to an array....one is a string, the second an int, and the third a double.

We've only been introduced to arrays and I don't know anything yet about pointers or linked lists, or any of the higher end stuff, so I feel like I'm somewhat limited in my options. I've worked all day trying to figure out a way to acquire input from the text file and assign it to the appropriate array. I've tried to use getline to read the input file and set a delimiter to separate each piece of data but I get an error when I try to use it more than once. From what I've read, this has to do with how I'm overloading the function but I'm at a loss at resolving it. Every explanation I've read about it goes beyond my current level of familiarity. Right now, I'm focused on this fragment of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < EMP_NUM; i++) // Get input from text file for names.
    getline(inFile, nameAr[i], '*');

for (int i = 0; i < EMP_NUM; i++) // Input for hours.
    getline(inFile, hoursAr[i], '*');

for (int i=0; i < EMP_NUM; i++) // Input for hourly rate.
    getline(inFile, hrateAr[i], '*');
```

I'm trying to use getline three times and write the data to three separate arrays, then make a series of calculations with them later and output them to another text file. The first instance of getline doesn't produce any compiler errors but the latter two do. I'm not quite sure of another solution to get the data into my arrays, so I'm at a loss. Any help would be great!

Comment: We're free to construct the input file as we wish, so long as it contains all the correct data. I've arranged it so that it contains three lines, one with a set of names, the other with hours, and the third with hourly rates. The names have a first initial and last name, followed by an asterisk acting as a delimiter. For example: J. Doe* J. Doee* ..... The latter two lines are just plain numbers separated by whitespace characters. I chose to use a delimiter with the first line since the first initial and last name both include a whitespace character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Instead of three different iteration, use only one

2) Pass string object in getline instead of pointers

```
string buf;
for (int i = 0; i < EMP_NUM; i++) // Get input from text file for names.
{
    getline(inFile, buf, '*');
    nameAr[i] = buf;
    getline(inFile, buf, '*');  //assuming delimiter is again *
    hoursAr[i] = atoi(buf.c_str() );  //C way to doing it...however in c++ u have to use stringstreams....
    getline(inFile, buf);
    hrateAr[i] = atof(buf.c_str() );;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you merely have three values in a file: a string, an int and a double. I assume they are delimited by whitespace.

If that is so then you don't need `std::getline()`. Rather, use the extraction operator:

```
std::ifstream file("input.txt");
std::string s;
if( ! (file >> s) ) {  // a single word extracted from the file
    // failure
}
int n;
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

What do the **compiler** errors say? Are you sure that the error is caused by `getline`? Maybe it's not because the `getline` calls but because of multiple declarations of `i`.

Comment: `i` is a loop variable in the code posted, and its scope should be limited to the for loop it was declared in. In this case (without curly braces), the line below it every time.

Comment: Yes, as you pointed out correctly: It *should* be limited to the `for` loop it was declared in. But compilers exist which add those variables to the scope in which the `for` loop occurs and not to the `for` loop itself only. As we don't know the compiler in use, we cannot exclude such behavior.

Comment: The second and third arrays are of `int` and `double`. Neither `hourAr[i]` nor `hrateAr[i]` are valid arguments for `getline`, so I guess that the problem is there. It's been quite long ago since I have seen a compiler with the broken for loop (VC6?)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, guys...I'm using Visual Studio 2010 at the moment. Is getline only valid for passing arguments to a string data type? I know cin.getline and ifstream getline are slightly different and are restricted to char arrays only...is getline the same way with strings?

Comment: Oh, and the particular error given by the compiler's IntelliSense in relation to the latter two getlines is: "No instance of overloaded function 'getline' matches the argument list."